# fontawesome with vue do not work in vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend, font-awesome

I tried to display fontawesome in my vue project I did all requierd steps in fontawesome documetations  I tri`enter code here`ed few tutorials but they are all useless I got this error in the console

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './scss/main.scss'
import 'normalize.css'
/* import the fontawesome core */
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

/* import specific icons */
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

/* import font awesome icon component */
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

/* add icons to the library */
library.add(faUserSecret)

/* add font awesome icon component */

createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .mount('#app')
  .component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

this is an error in console
[image]

Comment: That's not how you add components to Vue, you should read the Vue/Font Awesome docs first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use component() function before mount() function

try this;

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './scss/main.scss'
import 'normalize.css'
/* import the fontawesome core */
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

/* import specific icons */
import { faUserSecret } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

/* import font awesome icon component */
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

/* add icons to the library */
library.add(faUserSecret)

/* add font awesome icon component */

createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
  .mount('#app')
```

Comment: Tell the user where to put the code snippet.